# How to extract multiple values from html to java?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from html source code to my java project.
The html is taken from "Bing search images" and I wanna get all the images from the `<a>` tag. This is the html code:

```
<a href="/images/search?q=nba&amp;view=detailv2&amp;&amp;&amp;
id=FE19E7BB2916CE8B6CD78148F3BC0656D151049A&amp;
selectedIndex=3&amp;
ccid=2%2f7OBkGc&amp;
simid=608035681734625885&amp;
thid=JN.tdPCsRj4HyJzbwA%2bgXsS8g" 
ihk="JN.tdPCsRj4HyJzbwA+gXsS8g" 
m="{ns:&quot;images&quot;,k:&quot;5070&quot;,dirovr:&quot;ltr&quot;,
mid:&quot;FE19E7BB2916CE8B6CD78148F3BC0656D151049A&quot;,
surl:&quot;http://www.nba.com/gallery/rookie/070727_1.html&quot;,
imgurl:&quot;http://www.nba.com/media/draft_class_3_07_070727.jpg
&quot;,
ow:&quot;300&quot;,docid:&quot;608035681734625885&quot;,oh:&quot;192&quot;,tft:&quot;58&quot;}" 
mid="FE19E7BB2916CE8B6CD78148F3BC0656D151049A" 
t1="The 2007 NBA Draft Class" 
t2="625 x 400 · 374 kB · jpeg" 
t3="www.nba.com/gallery/rookie/070727_1.html" 
h="ID=images,5070.1"><img data-bm="16" 
src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=JN.tdPCsRj4HyJzbwA%2bgXsS8g&amp;w=217&amp;h=142&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=90&amp;o=4&amp;pid=1.1" 
style="width:217px;height:142px;" width="217" height="142">
</a>
```

and this is how i tried to extract it but no succeeded:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String title = "dog";
        String url =    "https://www.bing.com/images/search?q="+title+"&FORM=HDRSC2";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

            for (Element el : img) {
                String src1 = el.absUrl("imgurl");
                String src2 = el.absUrl("surl");
                System.out.println(src1 + " " + src2);      
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Any idea if it's possible?

Comment: at which point you do not succeeded? `Jsonp.connect` or inside `for loop`?? Or ?

Comment: the connection working fine but no result on the           `String src1 = el.absUrl("imgurl");
                String src2 = el.absUrl("surl");`

Comment: Are you using any IDE to develop? If so try to debug and find the correct expression.

Comment: Look at the HTML code . you can tell me how can i get the "imgurl" and the "surl" values?

Comment: I dont know html, just java sorry. so how can i extract it?

Comment: `don't know HTML just Java`? You use web everyday, at least you should be familiar with HTML.

Comment: yhea ..i know sorry. i'm tring to learn it now

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your `<a>` element has attribute `m`, not `imgurl` or `surl`, and that `m` contains a JSON which in turn contains `imgurl` and `surl`. So you should extract JSON from `m`:

```
String m = el.attr("m");
```

And then parse that `m` as a JSON, using any library you like, e.g. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
class MJson {
    private String imgurl;
    private String surl;

    ...
}

MJson mJson = new Gson().fromJson(m, MJson.class);
String src1 = mJson.getImgurl();
String src2 = mJson.getSurl();
```

Comment: Wow thanks! but what sould i need to write insted the `...` please

Comment: @mattmatt getters and setters

Comment: I'm still get `@null`

Comment: @mattmatt, at which place?

Comment: src1 and src2. it's look like the Gson not getting data at all